# Make sites clickable links in the "Hide communities" page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, hyperlinks

When in [Hide communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) section *(no matter on which site)*, the sites are not clickable

[image: plain text communities]

Can they be clickable? It shouldn't be much of a trouble and provides a lot of convenience for lazy people (there are plenty out there).

Comment: Can you explain why the current implementation is problematic? Why does this need to change?

Comment: I have an account for plenty sites and just today wanted to Unhide some communities, but wanted to check exactly what type of Q&A site it is and, to my surprise, that text was just that, a text, without a link towards that site. So I had to make 2 more server requests just to receive that information, instead of having it where it should already be.

Comment: The explanation belongs in the question, not the comments ;)

Comment: Actually the answer to your question, "the why", is obvious for those who will implement it. If the community will downvote because of the lack of obvious details - well, I'm used to that :).

Comment: What is obvious to you is not obvious to everyone. I'm not sure I understand your disinclination to make your question better. Feature requests generally need to be explained and supported if you want to get the best response. You're free to leave it as is but it's difficult to guess why this is beneficial if not explained. The staff may find it obvious but they're not the ones voting in many cases.

Comment: I totally agree with you that it might not be obvious for everyone. It's a personal decision to just do my job at the minimum and don't bother with the details, due to multiple requests in which I invested a lot of time to make sure I cover all the questions and still get plenty downvotes. The usual feedback is: if a giant liked it (in the comments, so that it's visible), the community liked it as well, if a giant disliked it, the community disliked it as well - no matter how many details I've given.

Comment: What is a giant? If you're talking about me, I haven't disliked anything and if you edited it to explain, I'd delete my comments...

Comment: Not at all @Catija. I have plenty requests on other meta sites, so I was talking about past experiences.

Comment: Voting on Meta feature requests works differently. People vote on whether or not they agree or disagree with the premise, rather than based on whether the question is of good or bad quality. So a well-reasoned feature request can get downvotes if others disagree with your reasoning or have counter-reasoning of their own.

Comment: @Adelin It's a perfectly reasonable improvement for us to make to the site. I've marked it [tag:status-deferred] simply because it isn't super high priority.